# r raster statistics per grid cell zone

Tags: r, raster

I would like to calculate grid cell statistics in zones that are within graticules (see plot).

[image]

Getting the cellstats for the shown grid cell is not difficult, but how could this be done for all grid cells?

```
library(raster)

filename <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r=raster(filename)

plot(r)
e=extent(180000,181000,330000,331000)
plot(e,add=T)
grid()

x=crop(r,e)
cellStats(x,mean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reproducible example did not work for me as I am not sure why `r[r>500]=1` and `r[r<=500]=NA` are used while your original plot is different?! Plus, I was not sure what `rx` is?! One way to do this as below:

```
library(raster)

filename <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r=raster(filename)

# r[r>500]=1
# r[r<=500]=NA

plot(r)
xmin <- seq(178000, 181000, 1000)
xmax <- seq(179000, 182000, 1000)
ymin <- seq(329000, 333000, 1000)
ymax <- seq(330000, 334000, 1000)

zonal.mtx <- matrix(nrow=length(xmin), ncol=length(ymin))

library(spatialEco)
for (i in 1:length(xmin)){
  for (j in 1:length(ymin)){
    e=extent(xmin[i],xmax[i],ymin[j],ymax[j])
    plot(e,add=T)
    grid()
    p <- as(e, 'SpatialPolygons')  
    crs(p) <- crs(r)

    p$ID=j
    p <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p,p@data) 

    zonal.mtx[i,j] <- zonal.stats(x=p, y=r, stat=sum, trace=TRUE, plot=TRUE)
    #print(zonal.mtx[i,j])
  }

}
```

**Note:** this plots each portion of the data while calculating zonal stats. I am sure you already know that you can also define your own function for using in `zonal.stats` rather than `sum`, `mean` etc.

Comment: You are right...but your example works as intended, thanks!

Comment: No worries Henk, I also edited the post a tiny bit.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the zonal.stats function, of which I was not aware. Looking into the code, it does crop. My original idea was to use a nested foreach loop for the extents, and the raster::zonal function.

Comment: My bad @Henk, edited my response. I guess you can still use `foreach`.

Comment: It should be easy to do it via raster::zonal and foreach, but I get a problem. I will open a new question.